# ClosedXML insertData(List<Double>, True) results in only the first row as a Number while rest of the rows as general

Tags: closedxml

I am using ClosedXML to handle exporting data from an addin to an excel file.
I first get my data as List and convert it to List:

```html
 List<double> columnData_lst = curr_data_woHdrs_lst[colIndex].Select(str => (double)KDS_Convert.parseOrDefault(str, 0.00)).ToList();
```

I then inserts it, Transposed since i want it to go in as a Column not as a row:

```html
worksheet.Cell(startRow, currCol).InsertData(curr_data_woHdrs_LstTrans_lst[colIndex], true);
```

My Expectation is that the whole column would be formatted as Number in Excel.  Instead, the first cell of the current Column is formatted as Number.
Any ideas of what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys,  all work as expected.  i had an issue with the Transpose field in insertData, it should have been set to false, not true.  this misunderstanding and another write happening over the same region got me a bit confused about what is happening.
So code works as expected...